# Geocode + Autocomplete + Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, geocode

I am reading RailsCast #102 on AutoCompelte, however this describes how to do stuff with a .json file, however if I'm using something like Geocode it doesn't have such a thing since it's calling information from Google Maps. I have found many guides to connect jQuery AutoCompelte to Rails and Geocode to Rails, but not one that does all three. So I was wondering how do I go about doing an AutoCompelte form which calls data from Geocode.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide more information about what Geocode library you are talking about? And what type of data you are wanting to show in the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at https://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/ which is a ready solution for autocompleting Google Maps locations.

You can then listen to the geocomplete events and populate your fields as you like.